# Unrolling periodical events in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've got a database with two tables, that I want to combine. One of the tables contains "incidental events", which just occur once. Next to this, I also have "periodical events". Now I want to combine these two in a view.

The incidental one simply has two columns, one called `changes`, the other one called `date`. The periodical one has three columns, `changes`, `startDate` and `endDate`. The difference between these two can be a maximum of 50 years, so manually typing out one case for every day is not going to work. Both views also have an AI ID. In this view I want to have a column `date` and a column `changes`.

To achieve this I want to unroll the periodical changes table, so that it shows one entry for every day in between the startDate and endDate. For instance:

incidental changes:

```
date       | change
09/08/2015 | 5
11/08/2015 | 10
```

periodical changes:

```
startDate  | endDate    | change
09/08/2015 | 12/08/2015 | 7
```

These two I want combined into:

changes view:

```
date       | change
09/08/2015 | 5
09/08/2015 | 7
10/08/2015 | 7
11/08/2015 | 10
11/08/2015 | 7
12/08/2015 | 7
```

My idea is to use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM incidental_changes,(
    SET @id = (SELECT min(ID) AS min FROM periodical_changes WHERE 1)
    SET @maxID = (SELECT max(ID) AS max FROM periodical_changes WHERE 1)
    WHILE (@id <= @maxID) DO
        SET @firstDate = (SELECT startDate FROM periodical_changes WHERE id = @id)
        SET @lastDate = (SELECT endDate FROM periodical_changes WHERE id = @id)
        WHILE (@firstDate <= @lastDate) DO
             SELECT @firstDate AS date, change FROM periodical_changes WHERE id = @id
             @firstDate = @firstDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
        END
        @id = @id + 1
    END
) WHERE 1
```

This gives me an error,

> CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED VIEW `all_periodicals` AS SELECT * FROM
>   incidental_changes,( SET @id = (SELECT min(ID) AS min FROM
>   periodical_changes WHERE 1) SET @maxID = (SELECT max(ID) AS max FROM
>   periodical_changes WHERE 1) WHILE (@id <= @maxID) DO SET @firstDate =
>   (SELECT startDate FROM periodical_changes WHERE id = @id) SET
>   @lastDate = (SELECT endDate FROM periodical_changes WHERE id = @id)
>   WHILE (@firstDate <= @lastDate) DO SELECT @firstDate AS date, change
>   FROM periodical_changes WHERE id = @id @firstDate = @firstDate +
>   INTERVAL 1 DAY END @id = @id + 1 END ) WHERE 1
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SET @id = (SELECT min(ID) AS min FROM periodical_changes WHERE
>   1) SET @' at line 5

and I'm guessing that if I'd manage to fix this error there'd be more. So, is there any way to do this the way I want, or do I have to look for a different approach?

---

EDIT:
Okay, so far I have not found a way to do this in a view or so. So instead I am now using a routine. This routine has one parameter, account INT. The definition I am using so far is as followed:

```
    BEGIN
    DECLARE periodicalID int;
    DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE periodicalCursor CURSOR
        FOR SELECT periodicals.periodicalID FROM periodicals WHERE periodicals.accountID = account;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE results LIKE incidentials;
    ALTER TABLE results DROP INDEX date;

    SET @periodicalID = -1;
    OPEN periodicalCursor;
    allPeriodicals: LOOP

    FETCH periodicalCursor INTO periodicalID;

    IF (v_finished) THEN
        LEAVE allPeriodicals;
    END IF;


    SELECT periodicals.startDate,periodicals.numberOfPeriods,periodicals.period,periodicals.endDate,periodicals.money FROM periodicals WHERE periodicals.periodicalID = periodicalID AND periodicals.accountID = account INTO @startDate, @numberOfPeriods, @period,@endDate,@money;

    SET @intervalStatement = "SELECT ? + INTERVAL ? ";
    SET @intervalStatement = CONCAT(@intervalStatement,@period," INTO @res");
    PREPARE intervalStatement FROM @intervalStatement;

    WHILE @startDate <= @endDate DO
        EXECUTE intervalStatement USING @startDate,@numberOfPeriods;
        SET @startDate = @res;
        INSERT INTO results(accountID,date,money) VALUES (account,@startDate,@money);
    END WHILE;

    END LOOP allPeriodicals;

    INSERT INTO results(accountID,date,money) SELECT accountID,date, money FROM incidentials WHERE incidentials.accountID = account;

    SELECT * FROM results ORDER BY date;

END
```

This poses the problem of performance though. With only one periodical entry spread over a year this query already takes about 16 seconds. So even though this approach works, I either did something wrong causing it to take this long or this is not the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Let me presume you have a `numbers` table.  Then you can do:

```
select i.date, i.change
from incidental
union all
select date_add(p.startDate, interval n.n - 1 day), p.change
from periodic p join
     numbers n
     on date_add(p.startDate, interval n.n - 1 day) <= p.endDate;
```

For a select query, you can generate the numbers using a subquery, if you know the maximum length.  Something like:

```
select i.date, i.change
from incidental
union all
select date_add(p.startDate, interval n.n - 1 day), p.change
from periodic p join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
      select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
     ) n
     on date_add(p.startDate, interval n.n - 1 day) <= p.endDate;
```

This doesn't work in a view, however.  For that, you really do need a `numbers` table.

Comment: To be honest I don't get what the use of the `numbers` table would do. Also, as I just edited in the main post, the amount of days possible between the startDate and endDate is too big to manually type out.

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg . . . The numbers table is used to generate the additional rows you want for each day in the period.

Comment: @GordenLinoff Okay, but then my problem would be that, if I update my periodicals table, the old records would still be in there. I guess that could be fixed by giving them a relationship, but it sounds like in this case the insert query would get very heavy. Also, considering that this would require a while statement, as far as I know this could only be done in a procedure.